# Gemfile when developing between two platforms

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, windows-7, if-statement, gemfile

I am carrying out some development of a Ruby on Rails app between a Windows machine and linux machine. Not ideal but Ruby on Windows has improved a lot. Anyway i read that you can implement an IF statement so for example I have implemented this

```
 source 'https://rubygems.org'

 if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /win32/

 gem 'rails', '3.2.3'
 gem 'sqlite3'

 group :assets do
 gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
 gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
 gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :git => 'git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git'
 gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
 end

 gem 'jquery-rails'
 gem 'nokogiri'
 gem 'httparty'
 gem 'devise'

 else

gem 'rails', '3.2.3'
gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.6'

group :assets do
gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :git => 'git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git'
gem 'less-rails'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer', '0.10.2'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'httparty'
gem 'devise'

end
```

So this morning I merged my linux branch into the master branch (windows) and now i get the message

```
Could not find the less-rails in any of the sources
```

So it seems as if the IF statement has not worked or there is an issue with my bootstrap.css.less file in assets as I use this in my linux branch

How can i get this to work, so either have less working on both platforms or get windows to ignore the less gem

has anyone got around this before

UPDATE

Ok so i have found that if I specify

```
:platform => :ruby
```

after the less-rails gem it ignores it (though I had to add to execjs and rubyracer aswell) due to js runtime conflicts.. So question still remains as to what is wrong with my IF/ELSE statement

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you rebuilt the bundle lock file?

Try this on your Windows machine:

```
bundle install
bundle update
```

To learn about bundle, Gemfile, Gemfile.lock, and why you need to rebuild the lock when you switch platforms: http://gembundler.com/rationale.html

Comment: thanks for your answer, would you mind explaining what this will do, also my understanding of the lock file isnt 100%, any good resources that explain it really well or do you have a simple explanation, thanks again

Comment: Yehuda Katz has a good post related to this: http://yehudakatz.com/2011/05/30/gem-versioning-and-bundler-doing-it-right/